# what is the logic or code to solve

Tags: python

The input will consist of an even number of lines of text. The input will be terminated by a blank line. Suppose there are 2n lines of input. Your program should print out the last n lines of the input, i.e., the second half of the input, followed by the first n lines, i.e., the first half of the input.

E.g., if the input is the following:

our dear friend,

let's eat

then the output should be:

let's eat

our dear friend,

Comment: This looks like a homework question.

Comment: yes its a homework question but they agree that we can take anyone help to solve

Comment: i = 1
                                                                                                             
 while 1:
                                                                                                               
  line = input()
                                                                                                                   
     if line==' ':

Comment: While it may be ok with your instructor, it's not the type of question that stackoverflow is for. We expect you to do most of the work. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ohhkk i agree but i want some help to solve this.I have to submit it today.tell me logic atleast. I will try to do it myself

Answer (score 0):

```
   def homeworkAssignment():
        arrText = []
        line = input()
        while line != "":
            arrText.append(line)
            line = input()
        middle = len(arrText) // 2
        for i in range(middle, len(arrText)):
            print(arrText[i])
        for i in range(middle):
            print(arrText[i])
```